# How to track traffic on my server in real time?

Tags: server, apache2, network-monitoring

I was wondering if I deploy a server at home, with apache2. I would like to know how much traffic is currently on my site, in real time.

Please and thank you.

:)

Comment: What kind of traffic? Number of page hits, or how much bandwidth is used/ number of bytes transferred via network interface?

Comment: @txwikinger all the above! long time no see!

Comment: Well.. have been busy with other Ubuntu stuff :D

Comment: Use [JetHTTP](https://launchpad.net/jethttp) :) Seriously though, I am curious to know if there is a way to do this with Apache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install the package `iptraf` which gives you realtime monitoring of various tcp and udp information. Page hits are realtime logged in the apache log that you have configured. You can either scan that file for number of lines matching your time period, or you can use some like [piwik](http://piwik.org/) for your apache server which gives you analysis similar to google analytics.

Answer (score 5):

I frequently add the [status module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html) to my apache configuration so that I can examine the running state of Apache (this example restricts access to only `localhost` status requests).

This goes in the virtualhost configuration:

```
 # Server status
 <IfModule mod_status.c>
  <Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
  </Location>
 </IfModule>
```

This goes in the general server configuration (I used `/etc/apache2/conf.d/10status.conf`):

```
# Turn on extended status collection
<IfModule mod_status.c>
    ExtendedStatus On
</IfModule>
```

And then I make sure `mod_status` is enabled:

```
sudo a2enmod status
```

After that, I can just visit http://your-virtual-host.example.com/server-status and get all kinds of details, including the high-level summary, like this:

```
Server uptime: 7 days 22 hours 56 minutes 45 seconds
Total accesses: 292855 - Total Traffic: 5.6 GB
CPU Usage: u85.78 s8.21 cu1.49 cs0 - .0139% CPU load
.426 requests/sec - 8.5 kB/second - 19.9 kB/request
2 requests currently being processed, 8 idle workers
....
Srv PID Acc M   CPU     SS  Req Conn    Child   Slot    Client  VHost   Request
0-1 27078   0/9/21119   _   0.06    3   101 0.0 0.04    372.17  67.195.113.233  example.com GET /foo.php?state=ND&thing=Madison
1-1 -   0/0/21273   .   0.01    137 0   0.0 0.00    402.35  128.61.99.146   example.com GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
....
```

I especially like the requests/sec, and the detailed report about what URLs are being (or were recently) served.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using [apachetop](http://www.jeremyjones.com/apachetop/), unfortunately it seems the development stopped, but it works well.

[This site](http://github.com/JeremyJones/Apachetop) is more recent.

Comment: apachetop is cool. able to view summary realtime accessed page.

Comment: `apachetop` is more cool that `iptraf` as for me :)

Answer (score 2):

If every 5 minutes or so is realtime enough for you, take a look at [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/). It collects system information and displays them in nice graphs, see [here](http://munin.ping.uio.no/ping.uio.no/rossum.ping.uio.no.html) for a live example-installation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ssh root@HOST tcpdump -U -s0 -w - 'not port 22' | wireshark -k -i -

HOST = your webserver
Chose Statistics fro Menu and Click IO Graphs

Answer (score 1):

Try cacti.

```
aptitude install cacti
```